# Hello Big Brother. I mean, Google

Tags: discussion

Unless you've been in hibernation during the past year and a half you've probably heard of changes roiling the IT world, including due to the launch of new generative AI products [sucking all attention and new investment](https://www.mckinsey.com/capabilities/quantumblack/our-insights/the-state-of-ai-in-2023-generative-ais-breakout-year). For a different perspective on last year, take a look at this [past forecast of 2023](https://hbr.org/2023/01/where-is-tech-going-in-2023). There are naysayers who see the dominance of AI far in the future, others more optimistic (or [pessimistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nineteen_Eighty-Four)) who see doom (as in, this site's) as imminent.

Never satisfied to just stand by, the folks heading SE/SO have decided to, well, I don't know, I just take a peek at the main meta once in a while, and the response is an awfully confusing double-speaky combination of simultaneously rejecting and embracing AI. The latest (well, 6 days old now) is that [the Google has landed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/398127/our-partnership-with-google-and-commitment-to-socially-responsible-ai?cb=1). At present the collaboration appears to be limited to SO and should not affect this site. Thanks HarikrishnanM for reminding me of this.

Imminent dystopia? Me, I have "job" to do, I just get up and make the donuts. You? Keep that chin up! This site exists for many reasons. Find one for it to exist and share it with the world (I think I read that in a cat poster).

Feel free to judge, vent and opine below as you see fit.

Comment: That post says nothing, but the OP wrote an answer that news will come in $6$ to $8$ weeks, well.. You are angry because all the work that thousands of people have put in answers is being sold, and no gratitude is shown?

Comment: @MetalStorm There is a dose of sarcasm in the post. I am thankful that sites like this (and google) exist. I am not sure what to think, but never ignored the fact that SE needs to make a profit and that there has been turmoil. I am not especially upset but am surprised and a bit confused as to what this deal might mean. I thought the arrival of AI LLMs was further down the road. I am generally concerned about how AI and its use will evolve.  I am inured to leaders acting in their own best interests, being ignorant, the fact that business is business, and that there is no free lunch.

Comment: I posted this to bring the main meta post to the attention  of participants here who may have missed it.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I am quite unhappy about this Google partnership.

---

**My interpretation of this** is as follows:

> Today, we [announced an exciting new partnership with Google](https://stackoverflow.co/company/press/archive/google-cloud-strategic-gen-ai-partnership) to bring Google's [Gemini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemini_(chatbot)) to Stack Overflow and to provide Stack Overflow content directly within Google Cloud. You can read more details in [the blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2024/02/29/defining-socially-responsible-ai-how-we-select-api-partners).

If I am right, this means that we are providing data to Gemini, for it to frame its answers (just like how Copilot gives us the list of websites from which it takes its answers, Gemini also does so.

[image]

[image]

[image]

(*Notice the links down*)

Given this, I interpret that SE also will be providing data to Gemini for its answers.

**What issues do I have with this?** Firstly, who knows if Gemini is going to distort the clear image that we give through our answers and destroy every bit of clarity of the concept? The reader can verify using the sources given! But does he / she have time for it?

Secondly, most, if not all, sites on the SE network (especially the academic-oriented ones) have completely rejected the AI because of high inaccuracy and potential wrong answers it can give, while making it look correct (confirmation bias?).

Thirdly, this speaks of the high levels of hypocrisy in the core team - in the mornings we talk about stopping / controlling AI usage, and in the evening we talk about embracing AI - what's this? Won't this confuse anyone?

---

Nevertheless, Gemini, is in a deep controversy, for exhibiting **biased** content. It called [Indian PM Mr. Modi a fascist](https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/news/india/google-apologises-to-india-over-geminis-results-on-modi-calls-its-own-ai-platform-unreliable/articleshow/108193940.cms?from=mdr) (may not be relevant but important), brings up [racially coloured insults](https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/news/international/business/unacceptable-we-were-wrong-under-fire-google-ceo-pichai-reacts-to-gemini-ai-fall-out/articleshow/108062685.cms?from=mdr), and so on and so forth. That's another factor to consider.

---

But, as of present, AI is just a newborn baby, IMO. It has got a lot to learn before it can even think at a human level. Even then, it would still lack the amount of 6th sense we've got. End of day, the human mind only has to discern what it sees.

Also it has to be noted that Stack Overflow is only going through this - and not other sites on the SE network, but we have to consider ChemSE being a part of this ecosystem might be affected, and we have to plan measures for the same, in all cases.

AI in general is a curse on the ChemSE community due to the low quality AI-generated answers that manage to creep here.

---

Concluding this answer with a couplet from Thirukkural, which captures what we humans need to do for the timebeing until AI improves its accuracy:

> ***எப்பொருள் யார்யார்வாய்க் கேட்பினும் அப்பொருள்***
>
> ***மெய்ப்பொருள் காண்ப தறிவு.      - குறள் 423, அதிகாரம்: அறிவுடைமை***
>
> *epporuḷ yāryārvāyk kēṭpiṉum apporuḷ*
>
> $\text{ʲɛppoɾʉɭ jɑːrjɑːrʋɑːjk keːʈpɪnʉm əppoɾʉɭ}$
>
> *meypporuḷ kāṇpa taṟivu         - Couplet 423, Subject: Possession of Knowledge*
>
> $\text{ mɛjppoɾʉɭ kɑːɳbə t̪əɾɪʋʉ}$
>
> **Meaning:** The mark of wisdom is to discern the truth from whatever source it is heard.

Comment: True, there is no mention of SE at large that I could find in the main meta post. But I would guess an extension is "imminent". There might be factors that render that extension challenging but I think all the pieces of the puzzle are there. The baby is born, it knows how to learn and is being taught new ways to learn, an iterative process with the launch of products available to the general public. LLMs can get simple math wrong but symbolic math programs exist. It is just a matter of coupling different modes of analysis (of time, iow): eg https://aclanthology.org/2023.findings-emnlp.248.pdf

Comment: I suppose there is plenty of room to manipulate what answers it provides. I don't think this should be as relevant in a field like chemistry (as opposed to your political example).

Comment: Manipulation is a key issue in the context @BuckThorn. My political example was to showcase that (as it is not as visible in the academic context). In the sense that how the AI makes **wrong answers look like right ones.**

Comment: Sure, but that reduces the utility of an answer, presumably, as opposed to a political context, where some would say there is no wrong answer, just opinions. This site was designed from inception to reject opinion-based answers. By extension I suppose AI should be excluded until it proves reliable (not opinionated). However it might never get that far. AI builds a consensus answer from the information it is input. If that information is biased then the output will be biased. Junk in, junk out.

Comment: Or rather, AI training methods would need to exclude opinion, or include some feedback that reinforces correct answers, in the same way humans are educated. And so we see how expert-curated content is valuable.

Comment: 100% agree with your points @BuckThorn, whatever input that is fed in is only given out.

Comment: Anyway, I don't upvote because I don't agree entirely with your assessment (I think AI is going to get scary smart, even more than it already has) and that's what the votes are supposed to indicate, but your feedback is good! And you brought up the distinction of SE/SO - I should edit my post.

Comment: @BuckThorn, I have written my opinion based on current situations. It might get better as AI constantly updates itself.

Comment: Yeah, you're right that LLMs are less than useful right now in some tech fields. Programming languages are subject to strict (and narrow) rules of grammar so it makes sense that LLMs would succeed there. You might see how google sees value in SE though and how a collaboration could lead to increased accuracy.